# How to write in Fortran the equivalent of MATLAB's diff function?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, difference

I'd like to write a `function`/`subroutine` in Fortran90 which does the same as MATLAB's `diff` function, that is, it receives a multidimensional array `A` and an integer `dim` and calculates differences between adjacent elements of `A` along the array dimension specified by `dim`.

First of all, should it be a `function` or a `subroutine`? And why?

How to deal with the dimensions of `A`? For instance, if `A` is sized `(a,b,c)`, the output should be sized `(a,b-1,c)` if `dim` is `2`; and

I think the length along each dimensions is not a problem. But I don't know to handle the number of dimensions.

**EDIT:**
I got the point about the intrinsic function `eoshift`, that is, I could `eoshift` the matrix `A` along the dimension `dim` and then subtract it from the original one. Doing so, unfortunately, the output matrix would be iso-sized to `A`, whereas it should have the extent along the dimension `dim` diminished by 1. In this sense, I don't know how to declare an array based on a given shape (`REAL, DIMENSION(shape(A)) :: B` doesn't work). Actually, I don't now how to declare a variable of unknown rank in a `function`/`subroutine`.

Comment: Different dimensions should be handled by creating a generic interface to specific implementations for 1D, 2D, ...7D. And I would do it as a function with an allocatable result. You need Fortran 2003, though, Fortran 90 is hopelessly obsolete.

Comment: You shouldn't declare a variable of unknown rank, you should use generics, I already wrote that. And just allocate the result and make it allocatable (Fortran 2003). It is quite simple (the allocation).

Comment: So isn't it possible to do this in Fortran 90/95?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I chose to follow the path proposed by @Vladimir F (am I right?)

```
MODULE module1
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTERFACE lininterpmid1D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_1D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_2D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_3D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_4D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_5D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_6D
        MODULE PROCEDURE midpoint_7D
    END INTERFACE lininterpmid1D

    PRIVATE
    PUBLIC :: lininterpmid1D

CONTAINS

... ! here are the 7 functions of the interface

END MODULE module1
```

Comment: That's the solution? I would have been very happy to find some actual code implementation there tbh :)

Comment: @CTZStef, honestly I've tried to prune any memory of this language out of my brain, to make space for something more useful. That's to say I don't remember much about what I actually did at the time.

Comment: I never thought you would even bother answering my comment.  I would still have been happy to see that code implementation tho

Comment: I would certainly share it, but I don't have it anymore, simply put.

Comment: Looks like I’m going to have to use my brainz *sigh*